# jquery :first selector loop problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".wrap table tr:first").addClass("tr-top");
```

it works for the first table, but i have many tables under the div .wrap.
what should i do? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, this line returns the first in the set of all `tr` elements found.

```
$(".wrap table tr:first").addClass("tr-top");  // First <tr> of all that are found
```

So if you have 3 `table` elements, it will only return the first `tr` from the first table, since that will be the first `tr` element matched.

If you want the first `tr` for *each* table, you need `first-child`:

```
$(".wrap table tr:first-child").addClass("tr-top");  // First <tr> for each <table>
```

...which will return each `tr` that is a first child of its parent.

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The each loops through each table within .wrap.

```
$('.wrap table').each(function() {
    $('.wrap table tr:first').addClass('tr-top');
}};
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: This won't actually produce results any different from what the OP currently has.

Comment: thanks! but i think i've tried it as well seems doesn't work too me.